# Apple support contacted by someone pretending to be me

Tags: security, apple-id, accounts

Yesterday i received an automatic mail for apple thanking me to have contacted the support and there was a practice ID and my mail.

The problem is that i never contacted the apple support, so i further investigated it by going to the apple support practices website, inserted the ID and the mail and that showed me that someone has contacted the support asking for something about an iPhone 4 update, and on the field "Your contact info" there was my surname but a different name.

Worried by this situation i called the Apple support and explained.
The operator told me that he don't see anything under my name and probably someone was wrong when entered the mail to contact the support, so i can stay safe.

But i don't feel completely safe, also i'm quite sure that this was done in purpose by someone because some years ago i solded an iPhone 4 to a guy , after purged everything from it and disassociated by account from it, but this guy know my mail and some details about me and i can't completely trust him. We also litigated few months ago, and this guy's name is the same that i see on the ticket ID , but with my surname.

There is clearly too coincidences.

My question is, how i can i do in this case to prevent anything bad and feel really safe?

Comment: Ask the Apple support using the ticket number

Comment: Get a second opinion by contacting someone else at Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should way the risks and ensure that if in fact someone is trying to take advantage of your account or even using social engineering to compromise your account, you minimize the damage that could happen.

• You should call Apple support again, perhaps using the same ticket number, and explain your situation yet again. Explain to them what you just explained to us. If you can convince them, they will likely get a senior support advisor to handle the issue. Perhaps you can negotiate some sort of verbal password with Apple support such that anyone calling them on your behalf would need to know the verbal password before Apple would make any critical account changes. You also need to be careful that the other person does not convince Apple that they are the real you and you are the imposter.

• In order to make any account changes via Apple support, the caller needs to know some information about the account other than just the email address. After all, an email address is fairly public information. You need to make sure these pieces of info are not obvious. For example, your birth date would be required, however this is also fairly easy to find info.
You therefore need to make sure your security questions are secure, and by that I mean the answers to your security questions are not easily discovered information. Note that the answers to security questions do not need to be accurate. You just need to be able to remember them.
I also recommend setting up two-factor authentication on your Apple ID, which eliminates security questions with amore secure unique one-time code.

All security-related settings may be found at appleid.apple.com.